# JQuery remove selected rows from a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Suppose I have a table:

```
 <table id="mytable">
    <tr>1</tr>
    <tr>2</tr>
    <tr>3</tr>
    <tr>4</tr>
    <tr>5</tr>
    <tr>6</tr>
    ...
    ...
   </table>
```

I know you can use `('#mytable').find("tr:gt(n)").remove();`
to remove all rows after nth row.
But is there a similar function to let you specify a range of rows you want to remove? say I want to remove row 2 to row 5? or I just want to remove row 2?

do i have to add an id to each row to achieve this?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [jQuery slice(start,[end])](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) for a range and [eq(index)](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) for single rows.

```
var myRows = $("table tr").slice(1,5);
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this be OK?

`$('#mytable tr:gt(2):lt(5)').remove();`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#mytable').find('tr').filter(function(index){
    return index >=2 && index <=5;
}).remove();
```

Comment: Wouldn't this return things with `id="mytable"`? I don't think this returns `tr`s..

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I neglected the `find('tr')` bit in my answer. Fixed now.

Comment: That works, but there are built in methods that already do this.

Comment: True, and `slice` would probably be better in this one particular scenario, but my gut-instinct from his question is that "select rows 2-5" is more an example than what he actually needs to do. `jQuery.filter` can be applied in more generic scenarios, such as "only rows where a child checkbox is checked".

Comment: which a better solution is to use a better selector to get the checkboxes and than gets the rows. ;)

Comment: Why is that? If you select the checkboxes, then you have to loop through them and traverse up the tree to the row to remove that one row. Rinse and repeat. With a filter, you can simply check if each selected `tr` has a `input[type=checked]:checked` child, and immediate remove that row. It's actually less overhead for jQuery.

Comment: BUT you are doing a jQuery lookup on every iteration with `jQuery(this)` to get the input. That is expensive. Quick and dirty [jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/checkbox-select-table-test)

Answer (score 0):

Try function for filter it:

```
var rangeFunction = function(index){
  return index >=2 && index <=5;
};

$('#mytable').filter(rangeFunction).remove();
```

It is the common method. If you want just simple linear range, then try:

```
$("#mytable tr").slice(2, 4).remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use [:eq() selector](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/):

```
$("#mytable").find("tr:eq(index)").remove();
```

And to delete a range of rows you can use that selector and just loop through them